# JS timeout not working with function

Tags: javascript

I need some help with a part of my program which is suppose to time out. I have a key pad which allows 4 digits to be input then passes this code to another function. I needed a timer after the 4th digit for 1 second so the page will display the result before sending the key and clearing the screen. This is the original part that works.
    `setTimeout(alarm,1000);`
but when I add the function to send the key it stops working

```
    if(code.value.length == 4){
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(alarm(code.value),1000); 
}
}
function alarm(code){
        alert(code);
        emptyCode();
}
```

I have read that I cannot put a function within the timeout script so is there another way to do this

Comment: Use callback function `setTimeout(function() { alarm(ode.value); }, 1000);`

Comment: You can also use `setTimeout(alarm, 1000, code.value);` see [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Great thank both worked, spent ages on this